# The confusing about html document type in IE6

Tags: types, internet-explorer-6, document

it always say the css code `margin:0 auto;` could't let element center in IE6

but I found that if I set document type in html code ,

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

which created automatically in Visual Studio 2010 when I create html page

the  `margin:0 auto;` could let html element center in IE6 again

So why the document type would work?What it exactly this document mean?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers toggle between standards and [quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) based on the presence of the doctype declaration. Quirks mode is a backward compatibility mode in which the behavior of older browsers is imitated. This is done to accommodate pages that rely on the non-standard behavior of earlier browsers.